# Getting "POST requires exactly one file upload per request" in AWS Gateway

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have created a bucket in S3 and created an API at Gateway for that. I try to POST a file to the s3 bucket.

**My request is; (I used Chrome REST client/SOAUPUI etc)**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: lob-test-api.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywLoiMiBUjfoSuUjG
content-length: 157

------WebKitFormBoundarywLoiMiBUjfoSuUjG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload6"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundarywLoiMiBUjfoSuUjG--

....
```

The Response I get is;

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message>
<ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>83C6F58DCEA9A85B</RequestId>
<HostId>w3gxLb1CDJ8xPMUkhOH8sezIYC/OP/uaUHUvBlFQCXg453dkkTivjdhfb/uOZCY5KpUOoqfUeBA=</HostId>
 </Error>
```

I routed the request through tcpmon, and edited the  content-type header multipart/form-data  boundary to;
`------WebKitFormBoundarywLoiMiBUjfoSuUjG` . But still I get same error.

Why do I get this error?

It is a simple API to handle POST request.

**Edit:**

**Request**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryS280VEmBfACBZzzD
Content-Length: 8063
Source message

POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: lob-test-api.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryS280VEmBfACBZzzD
content-length: 8063

------WebKitFormBoundaryS280VEmBfACBZzzD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload1"; filename="persistence.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">


</persistence>
------WebKitFormBoundaryS280VEmBfACBZzzD--
```

**RESPONSE**

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message>
<ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>E79843688D0A0D29</RequestId>
<HostId>CbCQjV9Y7I1ocpd9QKhpAEEfH+io31NYZwhadPKTQRPLAjIvRa6w1uSg2API7DBwEieZM99wfGg=</HostId>
 </Error>
```

Comment: `[object Object]` definitely doesn't seem right.  Please show the entire form.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I ahve provided my Chrome REST client Request and response, I try to upload a xml file

Comment: The error message is deceptive.  You are missing almost all of the required form fields.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html#sigv4-HTTPPOSTFormFields

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Im not using HTML form to upload files. Im using simple REST clients such as Curl, Chrome REST client/soapui to do post. I do not understand what im doing wrong here

Comment: I set enctype: multipart/form-data header too. But still same error. But my GET and PUT are working

Comment: Ah. If you are not using a form then you should not be using `POST`.  You need `PUT` -- and none of this `multipart/form-data` wrapping.  Nothing other than the octets of the object should be in the request body.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  //If you are not using a form then you should not be using POST. You need PUT// Huhhh? Why? POST is to upload a new file. Put is used to update the existing resource. Why AWS uses in different manner?

Comment: Many people have that impression, but it isn't accurate. S3 is RESTfully correct in the use of `PUT`.  You `POST` *against* a resource (e.g. elsewhere, you might see `POST /cgi-bin/upload.cgi`, where upload.cgi is the resource that handles the upload, it is not an identifier for the resource you are uploading), you `PUT` to create or overwrite a resource in a true REST environment.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks a lot.